# How do you get DHCP scope information from a Cisco device? (IOS 12)

Tags: networking, cisco, dhcp

I'm trying to track down devices and network info on a rather large network with a bunch of subnets and VLANs and the like, most of which are served DHCP from Cisco [enterprise-grade] switches or routers.  In that vein, I'm looking to find out what the various DHCP pools/scopes are, but all the information I can find is on how to configure DHCP with Cisco IOS, which isn't helpful because I don't want to change the scopes, just get a display of what they are currently.

I can do a `show ip dhcp binding` to get a list of DHCP clients, with their IPs and guess about what the valid range for DHCP IPs is, but that's pretty undesirable... so what's the command to *display* that information (without altering the existing configurations)?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the question, but it sounds like you're just looking to find out what pools are configured?  `show running-config | begin dhcp pool`?

Comment: @ShaneMadden That's it exactly... I say you make it an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the relevant device, try `show ip dhcp pool`. To show exclusions, try `show run | i excluded-addresses`.

The following output is from a Cisco 4507 switch.

```
CORE#show ip dhcp pool

Pool VOICE :
 Utilization mark (high/low)    : 100 / 0
 Subnet size (first/next)       : 0 / 0 
 Total addresses                : 254
 Leased addresses               : 42
 Excluded addresses             : 101
 Pending event                  : none
 1 subnet is currently in the pool :
 Current index        IP address range                    Leased/Excluded/Total
 192.168.122.234      192.168.122.1    - 192.168.122.254   42    / 101   / 254  


Pool GUEST :
 Utilization mark (high/low)    : 100 / 0
 Subnet size (first/next)       : 0 / 0 
 Total addresses                : 254
 Leased addresses               : 9
 Excluded addresses             : 103
 Pending event                  : none
 1 subnet is currently in the pool :
 Current index        IP address range                    Leased/Excluded/Total
 192.168.111.165      192.168.111.1    - 192.168.111.254   9     / 103   / 254
```

And exclusions:

```
CORE#show run | i excluded-addresses
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.122.1 192.168.122.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.122.100 192.168.122.150
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.111.1 192.168.111.50
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.111.100 192.168.111.150
```